# How to correctly show point hover on Highcharts large heatmap

Tags: highcharts, heatmap

I'm trying to show a hover colour on the highcharts large heatmap.
I've read a few posts but they're mainly around the smaller heatmap.
They suggest using Series.states.hover.color (http://jsfiddle.net/sgurhhm0/1/) but this method does not work for the large heatmap.

I have made a mockup of the large heatmap using point events;

```
point: {
    events: {
       mouseOver: function (e) {
           if (this.color != '#3060cf') {
               this.originalColor = this.color;
               this.update({ color: '#3060cf' });
           }
       },
       mouseOut: function (e) {
           this.update({ color: this.originalColor });
           this.originalColor = null;
       }
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mattscotty/st3j35dx/
But I'd prefer to do it the correct way and this method is quite slow and seemingly cumbersome (and the code isn't very nice either).

Thanks in advance, Matt.

Comment: I run your second demo (http://jsfiddle.net/c8f23xcd/) and it seems that you achieve hover color, could you point me what is incorrect?

Comment: Sebastian, yes it works, but its quite slow when hovering to change the points.
Also the normal way of implementing the hover does not work on large charts.
I'm just checking that I'm doing it in the best way and if it is indeed a bug that Series.states.hover.color does not work?
To clarify, the issue is not the colour, but the hover.

Comment: @SebastianBochan any ideas?

Comment: The reason of that is calling update each time when you hover. Disable printing chart on canvas and use state.hover option. http://jsfiddle.net/937twae7/

Comment: @SebastianBochan ok thanks, I suspected that the issue was because of the canvas. Any plans to fix this? As the docs suggest canvas is more efficient for larger data sets.

Comment: In the canvas all points are single shape so at this moment we cannot refer to particular point and highlight SVG elem, like in hover state.